# How can I make a stretched header with centered content when I zoom out the browser

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a centered content but it doesn't take the full view.
And when I change the header's position to absolute it resolved the problem but when I zoom out, the content go to the left side.

Html code:

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="content">
            <header>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Element1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Element2</a></li>
                    <li><img src="img/profile.jpg" width="50" height="50"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Element3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Element4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </header>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px; }

#container .content {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1200px; }

#container .content header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #323232;
  width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it wouldn't, your `header` is inside `.content` which has a fixed width of `1000px` therefore your header occupies `100%` of that width. You need to either separate `header` from `.content` or change `content`'s fixed width.

Keep in mind that percentage widths are based on parents.

Working Example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #323232;
  width: 100%;
}

#container .content {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Element1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Element2</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/profile.jpg" width="50" height="50"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Element3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Element4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint optio debitis deleniti ex, eos nihil vitae delectus excepturi laborum beatae officiis aliquid adipisci. Modi tenetur obcaecati blanditiis, voluptates iure consectetur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S using the universal selector `*` is problematic to performance, please avoid using it.

Comment: And to center the Unordered List, what is the best way to do it (margin left only)?

Comment: @AmirNassal CSS centering-related questions have been asked many times on this site, try searching and if you fail to find a solution ask a new question. Generally speaking, first you need to have the `li` elements in one line by either making them `inline-block`s or `flexbox`es or `float` them to the left, then center their parent `ul` with `margin:0 auto` with a fixed `width` unless you want the nav to cover the entire width of header.